# How to handle Common data of ChoiceType with Symfony form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am going to create a form with one column ID Verification.
There are several options based on the system, same as Enum.

The Target page should be :

[image]

Here I have the property in Entity as :

```
/**
 * @var array<string>
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_verification_requirements", type="simple_array", nullable=true)
 */
private $idVerificationRequirements;
```

I am not sure how to build the form element and store the related data.
Do I need to save the specific data in database as constants table?
It seems that PHP does not support Enum.

At the same time I have to handle a frequency type in the form as well.
I have got some suggestions to create a new frequency type to handle the data like:

Frequency:

```
class Frequency{
private $count;
// $unit must be defined in FrequencyUnit
private $unit;
function __construct($c, $u)
{
    $this->count = $c;
    $this->unit = $u;
}}
```

Then FrequencyUnit:

```
abstract class FrequencyUnit
{
    const PER_DAY = "PER DAY";
    const PER_WEEK = "PER WEEK";
    const PER_MONTH = "PER_MONTH";
    const PER_YEAR = "PER_YEAR";
}
```

How to generate this in the form like a drop-down list or there is other better way to deal with this kind of thing?

One more question is that is there any way to display only a label in the form, just like sub-title?

Thank you very much for you help.

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Currently I have build the form type as below :

```
        ->add('frequencyCount', IntegerType::class,array('label' => 'Max Load Frequency'))
        ->add('frequencyUnit', ChoiceType::class,array(
            'choices' => array(
                'Per Day' => 'Per Day',
                'Per Week' => 'Per Week',
                'Per Month' => 'Per Month',
                'Per Year' => 'Per Year'
            ),
            'expanded' => false, 'multiple' => false
        ))
        ->add('idVerificationRequirements', ChoiceType::class, array(
                'label' => 'ID Verification Requirements',
                'choices' => array(
                    'Front' => 1,
                    'Back' => 2,
                    'Both' => 3
                ),
                'expanded' => true, 'multiple' => true
            )
        )
```

For Frequency I have add below get and set function to handle the form data.

```
 public function setFrequencyCount($count)
{
    $this->loadFreq->setCount($count);
    return $this;
}

public function getFrequencyCount()
{
    return $this->loadFreq->getCount();
}

public function setFrequencyUnit($unit)
{
    $this->loadFreq->setUnit($unit);
    return $this;
}

public function getFrequencyUnit()
{
    return $this->loadFreq->getUnit();
}
```

It seems work.
I am not sure if this should be the solution or maybe some better way.

For now, I just wonder if there is some way to manage the choices with ChoiceType. I don't want to list as array when building the form. Could I get the data from other class?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Should we presume you've gone through the [Symfony Forms documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html) and also {Doctrine Documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html)? If so, have you tried making a Form Class?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have list the way I am doing now. But still some questions there.

Comment: Hi there Bob. Make sure you upvote any comments on Stackoverflow. I helps people identify useful suggestions in case they have the same issues. I'll see if I can answer your question about the frequencyUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest creating a `FrequencyUnit` Entity for example like this:

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/Unit.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 *  @ORM\Table(name="unit")
 */
class Unit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="unit_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $unit_id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string")
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * Set value
     *
     * @param string $val
     *
     * @return Unit
     */
    public function setValue($val)
    {
        $this->value = $val;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get value
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

---

Then in your form use EntityType like so:

```
...
->add('unit', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:Unit',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'value',
))
...
```

---

You would need to still add the values to the Entity. Maybe in your Controller?

```
$unit = new Unit();
$unit->setValue('PER DAY');
...
```

Hopefully that helps. It's hard to give you a good thorough answer, as because there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Alvin. I am going to create a new table to handle all these information based on your suggestions. I think this should be the proper way to deal with these options.

Comment: Glad to help out!